# Convert label text to decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I was wondering if you can convert a label to a decimal.  I know this can be done with a textbox, but i'm trying to see if it will work with a label.  Here is the code, I'm getting error input message.

```
Label sitL = ((Label)FormView2.FindControl("SitUpsLabel"));
Label pushL = ((Label)FormView2.FindControl("pushUpsLabel"));
int count = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
decimal val = Decimal.Parse(sitL.Text);
decimal val2 = Decimal.Parse(pushL.Text);
```

Comment: What's "error input message"?

Comment: That should work, what error are you getting?

Comment: Learn to think like a programmer. "I'm getting error" doesn't tell us anything useful about what is happening.

Comment: Well `sitL.Text` and `pushL.Text` must of course be parsable (numeric) to decimal. Just debug the code and see what the values are.

Comment: check first your label is null or not

Comment: sorry forgot to post the error message. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem about doing that, but you won't get values set on client side as you do for textboxes. Labels are not posted to server and it seems to me that you're trying to process user input.

With that said, check that the content of the label can be converted to decimal. You could use [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) method that will return false instead of throwing an exception in case the string can't be converted.

Comment: Thank you! this makes much more sense to me now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your label is not posted on server from client

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the value of a label, which cannot be posted by a user; I can be pretty certain that this data was bound into that label by calling `DataBind`.

Since you yourself are providing data to the label, there is a much better way to get this data if you need it for processing.

You should use the [DataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.dataitem.aspx)  property of the FormView.

> The type of the Object returned by this property varies depending on
>   the data source. For example, when a SqlDataSource control is bound to
>   the FormView control, a DataRowView object is returned.

Like this:

```
var myData = (DataRowView)FormView2.DataItem;
decimal val = myData["sitL"];
decimal val2 = myData["pushL"];
```

Comment: Yes. But event if the `DataItem` were an object, getting the value bound to the label would simpler. Parsing the text of the label seems like a round about way of getting the value. You have to do it for textboxes, but there we have no better option.

Comment: Yeh, but what if the label value is set by javascript at the client.

Comment: Then it would not be sent to the server by asp.net. Label values are not posted back. They are present in an encrypted form in the `ViewState`. Any changes at the front end will not come to the server.

Comment: Since the value will never come from the the front end, there is no point doing `Decimal.Parse(sitL.Text)`. You would already know what you assigned to the label.